# How to import the numpy module on AWS lambda?

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, serverless

I am new beginner for AWS system, I am doing my python project, want to use AWS lambda function to run my serverless python program, I have all my resource on AWS S3 bucket, I would like to simply take one of my images from S3 bucket (let's say source-bucket), turn it to grey color and save it back to the other S3 bucket (result-bucket). 
My question is how to I import the numpy and the cv2 module on AWS lambda, 
I followed guide from https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/ 
however, it return me an error message:

```
An error occurred: NumpyLambdaFunction - Function not found:
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:......:function:numpy-test-dev-numpy (Service:
AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 404; Error code: ResourceNotFoundException;
Request ID: ....).
```

What can I do to fix this error? or is there another better method for doing so? (P.S. I am using the window computer)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

Run this command in your project root directory

```
pip install --target="." package_name
```

Zip your project folder and upload it on AWS

**Method 2**

[Check out this readme](https://gist.github.com/joseph-zhong/372a47bb618111dcd2c81008d00357b2)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got it done after I uninstall all the folder and file and repeat the step from the guide, I think the error happened because I mess up the folder structure, i.e I create the requirement.txt and other important stuff at ./venv/Scripts,

Comment: By the way, I am facing the another problem, when I want to import cv2 module on aws lambda, it told me unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 byes, I tried to fix the error by https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3, but it doesn't work at all. Does anyone one tell me how to import the boto3, cv2 and numpy on aws lambda